# How to use Variables in Functions

Tags: json, node.js, variables, fs

How do I achieve getting `userID` in

```
obj.userID = mystring;
```

to be `let userID = somerandomID`?

I'm trying to add objects into JSON files using the fs module in nodejs. Here is the full code

```js
'use strict';
var obj = require('./Referral/log.json');
const fs = require('fs');

let userID = `somerandomID`

fs.readFile('./Referral/log.json', (err, data) => {  
    if (err) throw err;
    var mystring = `O54G9egD`;
obj.userID = mystring;
     var config = JSON.parse(data);
fs.writeFile('./Referral/log.json', JSON.stringify(obj), function (err) {
  console.log(`Added Referral code to log.`);
});
});
```

I'm probably using the worst way to make amendments to my JSON file, so any better solution would be greatly appreciated.

JSON file :

`{"MrMinister":"bS1N793vTS","userID":"O54G9egD"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using obj[userID] instead of obj.userID

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Edit : Nevermind, it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! I had the same problem the other day